# Bootstrap Modal Not Running "showHint" Function

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

Please bear with me because I don't think I'm asking the right question in my title, but I have tons of code that I can share and hopefully you all can help me get on track. I'm hoping I'm just calling the wrong variable and I've just gone blind to my code.

I have a "dashboard" page that has a series of 10 bootstrap buttons. I've already created a modal that allows a user to lookup a "billing code" and depending on the result returned, the modal will expand to show the complete form and allow to add a new code or update an existing. I then duplicated the "billing code" files to create the modal for "client contact" information. When I click the button for the "client contact" modal, the dialog fires just fine, but when I type in an email address, nothing happens - whether the contact exists or not.

I've included the code for the dashboard, the working billing code modal and the not working client contact modal. I hope it's enough without being too much. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

dashboard.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('includes/config.php');

require_once('handlers/billing-code.handler.php');
require_once('handlers/clientContacts.handler.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
header("location: index.php?error=1");
}

$page->titleSet('Project Task List Dashboard');

// Load Classes
$admin = new Admin();
$projects = new Projects();
$helpers = new Helpers();

// run query to welcome user
$user = $_SESSION['user'];

$getUser = $helpers->genQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = $user");

switch ($getUser[0]['userTypeID']) {
case 1:
    $dashboard = 'includes/dashboards/super-admin-dashboard.php';
    break;
case 2:
    $dashboard = 'includes/dashboards/user-dashboard.php';
    break;
case 3:
    $dashboard = 'includes/dashboards/admin-dashboard.php';
    break;
case 4:
    $dashboard = 'includes/dashboards/mgr-dashboard.php';
    break;
case 5:
    $dashboard = 'includes/dashboards/pm-dashboard.php';
    break;
}

// include the admin dashboard options based on user type
require_once($dashboard);


// run query to get short list of open upcoming due projects
$openProjects = $helpers->genQuery("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE completed = 0 LIMIT 0,10");

$page->contentSet('



<table width="90%" align="center" cellspacing="5" cellspacing="10" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Project ID</th>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th align="left">Project Type</th>
        <th align="left">Assigned To</th>
        <th align="center">Due Date</th>
        <th align="center">% Complete</th>
        <th align="center">Status</th>
    </tr>
');

foreach ($openProjects AS $projects) {

// alternating rows
$x++;

$rowColor = (($x%2 == 0) ? 'white-row-bg' : 'gray-row-bg');

// run query to get staff information   
$staff = $helpers->genQuery("SELECT staffName FROM staff WHERE staffID = \"".$projects['staffID']."\"");

// run query to get project type information
$projectType = $helpers->genQuery("SELECT projectTypeName FROM projectType WHERE projectTypeID = \"".$projects['typeID']."\"");

// Calculate whether or not the project is on time

$ontime = $helpers->daysLeft($projects['dueDate']);

$icon = ($ontime > 0 ? "green" : "red");

$page->contentSet('
    <tr class="'.$rowColor.'">
        <td align="left">'.$projects['projectID'].'</td>
        <td align="left"><a href="detail.php?pid='.$projects['projectID'].'" title="Click the project name to update status">'. substr($projects['projectName'],0,30).(strlen($projects['projectName']) > 30 ? '...' : '').'</a></td>
        <td align="left"><a href="#" title="View all open '.$projectType[0]['projectTypeName'].' projects">'.$projectType[0]['projectTypeName'].'</a></td>
        <td align="left"><a href="#" title="View all open projects assigned to '.$staff[0]['staffName'].'">'.$staff[0]['staffName'].'</a></td>          
        <td align="center"><a href="#" title="View all projects that are due on '.date("n/j/Y",strtotime($projects['dueDate'])).'">'.date("n/j/Y",strtotime($projects['dueDate'])).'</td>
        <td align="center">'.$projects['percentComplete'].'%</td>
        <td align="center"><img src="images/'.$icon.'-light-icon.png" /></td>

        </td>
    </tr>
');
}

$page->contentSet('
</table>



');

include('modals/billing-codes-options-modal.php');

include('modals/client-contacts-options-modal.php');
display_page();
?>
```

working Billing Code Files

billing-codes-options-modal.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('includes/config.php');

echo '

<script src="js/showHint.js" type="text/javascript" languag="javascript"></script>
';

$page->contentSet('

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="addUpdateBillingCodes" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add/Update Billing Codes</h4>
          <p>To add a new billing code, simply type the 6-digit code into the field below. If the code already exists, you will then have the opportunity to update the code\'s existing information; otherwise, you will be able to add the new code and its details. <a href="billing-codes.php">Click here for the complete list of billing codes.</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="" method="post" name="billingCodes">
          <p>
          <label>Billing Code: </label>
          <input type="text" name="billingCode" size="30" onchange="showHint(this.value)" /> <span style="cursor:hand;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
          </p>
          <span id="lookup">
        </span>
          </form>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
');

echo '

<script>
/* must apply only after HTML has loaded */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addUpdateBillingCodes").on("submit", function(e) {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $(\'#addUpdateBillingCodes .modal-header .modal-title\').html("Result");
                $(\'#addUpdateBillingCodes .modal-body\').html(data);
                $("#addUpdateBillingCodes").remove();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log(status + ": " + error);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#submitForm").on(\'click\', function() {
        $("#addUpdateBillingCodes").submit();
    });
});
</script>
';



?>
```

showHint.js

```
// JavaScript Document

function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("lookup").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("lookup").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "modals/lookups/billingCodelookup.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

billing-code.handler.php

```
<?php

// load classes
$helpers = new Helpers();
$modals = new Modals();

// declare connection variable
$mysqli = new MySQLi(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_BASE);

// declare errors array variable
$errors = array();

// scrub the data input
$billingCode = $helpers->escapePostValues($_POST['billingCode']);
$billingCodeDepartment = $helpers->escapePostValues($_POST['billingCodeDepartment']);
$billingCodeNickname = $helpers->escapePostValues($_POST['billingCodeNickname']);

// determine if this is a new billing code

if (isset($_POST['addBillingCode']) && $_POST['billingCodeAdd'] == 1) { 
    // add new billing code to table
    $addBillingCodeQuery = "INSERT INTO billingCodes (billingCodeDepartment,billingCodeNickname,billingCode) VALUES ('".$billingCodeDepartment."','".$billingCodeNickname."','".$billingCode."')";      

    // if billing code has been added, display success message
    if (mysqli_query($mysqli,$addBillingCodeQuery)) {
        $errors['newrecord'] = '<p class="success center">Billing Code '.$billingCode.' has been successfully added.</p>';  
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['updateBillingCode']) && $_POST['billingCodeUpdate'] == 1) {
    // update existing billing code information
    $updateBillingCodeQuery = "UPDATE billingCodes SET billingCodeDepartment='$billingCodeDepartment', billingCodeNickname='$billingCodeNickname',billingCode='$billingCode' WHERE billingCode='$billingCode'";     

    // if the billing code information has been updated, display confirmation message
    if (mysqli_query($mysqli,$updateBillingCodeQuery)) {
        $errors['recordupdated'] = '<p class="success center">Billing Code '.$billingCode.' has been successfully updated.</p>';    
    }

}

?>
```

billingCodeLookup.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../../includes/config.php');

$helpers = new Helpers();

    $billingCode = $_GET['q'];

    $lookup = $helpers->genQuery("SELECT * FROM billingCodes WHERE billingCode=\"".$billingCode."\"");

    echo '<p><label for="billingCodeDepartment">Department: </label><input type="text" name="billingCodeDepartment" value="'.$lookup[0]['billingCodeDepartment'].'" size="30" /></p>';
    echo '<p><label for="billingCodeNickname">Nickname: </label><input type="text" name="billingCodeNickname" value="'.$lookup[0]['billingCodeNickname'].'" size="30" /></p>';

    if ($lookup) {
        echo '
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="billingCodeUpdate" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" name="updateBillingCode" value="Update Billing Code" class="label-indent" />
        </p>';
    }

    else {
        echo '
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="billingCodeAdd" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" name="addBillingCode" value="Add New Billing Code" class="label-indent" />
        </p>';
    }

?>
```

Not Working Client Contact Lookup Files

client-contact-options-modal.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('includes/config.php');
// modal form for adding comments to a project

echo '

<script src="js/clientLookup.js" type="text/javascript" languag="javascript"></script>
';

$page->contentSet('

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="addUpdateClientContacts" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add/Update Client Contacts</h4>
          <p>To add a new contact, simply type in the email address of the contact into the field below. If the client contact already exists, you will then have the opportunity to update the contact\'s existing information; otherwise, you will be able to add the new contact and its details.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="" method="post" name="clientContacts">
          <p>
          <label for"clientContactEmail">Email Address: </label>
          <input type="text" name="clientContactEmail" size="20" onchange="showHint(this.value)" /> <span style="cursor:hand;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
          </p>
          <span id="lookup">
        </span>
          </form>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
');

echo '

<script>
/* must apply only after HTML has loaded */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addUpdateClientContacts").on("submit", function(e) {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $(\'#addUpdateClientContacts .modal-header .modal-title\').html("Result");
                $(\'#addUpdateClientContacts .modal-body\').html(data);
                $("#addUpdateClientContacts").remove();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log(status + ": " + error);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#submitForm").on(\'click\', function() {
        $("#addUpdateClientContacts").submit();
    });
});
</script>
';
?>
```

clientContactLookup.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../../includes/config.php');

$helpers = new Helpers();

    $email = $_GET['q'];

    $lookup = $helpers->genQuery("SELECT * FROM clientContacts WHERE clientContactEmail=\"".$email."\"");

    echo '
        <p><label for="clientContactFirst">First name: </label><input type="text" name="clientContactFirst" value="'.$lookup[0]['clientContactFirst'].'" size="30" /></p>
        <p><label for="clientContactLast">Last name: </label><input type="text" name="clientContactLast" value="'.$lookup[0]['clientContactLast'].'" size="30" /></p>
        <p><label for="clientContactPhone">Phone: </label><input type="text" name="clientContactPhone" value="'.$lookup[0]['clientContactPhone'].'" size="30" /></p>
        <p><label for="clientContactExt">Extension: </label><input type="text" name="clientContactExt" value="'.$lookup[0]['clientContactExt'].'" size="30" /></p>'
    ;

    if ($lookup) {
        echo '
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="clientContactUpdate" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" name="updateClientContact" value="Update Client Contact" class="label-indent" />
        </p>';
    }

    else {
        echo '
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="clientContactAdd" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" name="addClientContact" value="Add New Client Contact" class="label-indent" />
        </p>';
    }

?>
```

clientLookup.js

```
// JavaScript Document

function clientLookup(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("lookup").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("lookup").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "modals/lookups/clientContactLookup.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

clientContacts.handler.php

```
<?php

// load classes
$helpers = new Helpers();
$modals = new Modals();

// declare connection variable
$mysqli = new MySQLi(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_BASE);

// declare errors array variable
$errors = array();

// scrub the data input
$clientContactEmail = $helpers->escapePostValues($_POST['clientContactEmail']);
$clientContactFirst = $helpers->escapePostValues($_POST['clientContactFirst']);
$clientContactLast = $helpers->escapePostValues($_POST['clientContactLast']);
$clientContactPhone = $helpers->escapePostValues($_POST['clientContactPhone']);
$clientContactExt = $helpers->escapePostValues($_POST['clientContactExt']);

// determine if this is a new client contact

if (isset($_POST['addClientContact']) && $_POST['clientContactAdd'] == 1) { 
    // add new billing code to table
    $addClientContactQuery = "INSERT INTO clientContacts (clientContactFirst,clientContactLast,clientContactPhone,clientContactExt,clientContactEmail) VALUES('".$clientContactFirst."','".$clientContactLast."','".$clientContactPhone."','".$clientContactExt."','".$clientContactEmail."')";     

    // if contact has been added, display success message
    if (mysqli_query($mysqli,$addBillingCodeQuery)) {
        $errors['newrecord'] = '<p class="success center">Contact information for '.$clientContactFirst.' '.$clientContactLast.' has been successfully added.</p>'; 
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['updateClientContact']) && $_POST['clientContactUpdate'] == 1) {
    // update existing client contact information
    $updateClientContactQuery = "UPDATE clientContacts SET clientContactFirst='$clientContactFirst',clientContactLast='$clientContactLast',clientContactPhone='$clientContactPhone',clientContactExt='$clientContactExt',clientContactEmail='$clientContactEmail' WHERE clientContactEmail='$clientContactEmail'";      

    // if the contact information has been updated, display confirmation message
    if (mysqli_query($mysqli,$updateClientContactQuery)) {
        $errors['recordupdated'] = '<p class="success center">Contact information for '.$clientContactFirst.' '.$clientContactLast.' has been successfully updated.</p>';   
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: There is not enough code in this question

Comment: what additional code do I need to provide?

Comment: I think another 50 files would do.

Comment: ha!I can never win - either too much or not enough :(

Answer (score 0):

This actually wound up being a very simple fix: I didn't realize I was using the same span id in both modal files (). The onchange event now passes the id as a variable to the showHint function and the file structure has been reduced to requiring only one javascript file.